# Habilitar ou desabilitar botões de navegação C#

Tags: c#

No *binding navigator* da minha tabela tenho os seguintes botões:

```
inserir, cancelar edição, excluir e salvar (figura anexa).
```

Eu queria deixar o `inserir` e `excluir` desabilitados quando começar uma edição em qualquer campo da minha tabela (tanto na guia form como na grid), e voltar a habilitá-los caso as alterações sejam salvas ou canceladas.
Pensei que fosse fácil fazer isso, mas realmente não estou a conseguir.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, colete os nomes dos botões que tu quer desabilitar, para isso clique uma vez neles e vá em Propriedades e veja o parâmetro Name

Quando começar a edição? Tu deve dar duplo clique em cada `textBox` e na `DataGridView` e adicionar o código dentro de cada método criado:

```
Nome-Botão-Inserir.Enabled = false;
Nome-Botão-Excluir.Enabled = false;
```

Para habilitar é só fazer o inverso, duplo clique no botão de salvar e cancelar e colocar os códigos:

```
Nome-Botão-Inserir.Enabled = true;
Nome-Botão-Excluir.Enabled = true;
```

**Dica**:
O menu de controle criado pelo Visual não é muito intuitivo, sugiro que crie buttons (Adicionar, Cancelar, Salvar, Limpas dados) em vez de usa-los. Para cada botão tu pode usar os códigos no evento _Click:

**Adicionar** (add)

```
desBloq(); //método para ativar todos os campos para edição (evita que um usuário coloque dados antes de clicar no botão de add)
this.TABELABindingSource.AddNew();
this.add.Enabled = false;
```

**Excluir/Cancelar**

```
if (nomeTextBox.Enabled == false) { } // se os campos tiverem bloqueado ele não faz nada
else
{
    this.TABELABindingSource.RemoveCurrent(); //remove registro atual
    Bloq(); //bloqueia todos campos
    this.add.Enabled = true; // habilita botão add
}
```

**Salvar**

```
this.Validate(); //valida
this.TABELABindingSource.EndEdit(); // indica fim de edição
this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.bibDigitalDataSet); //atualiza a conexão
Bloq(); //bloqueia todos campos
this.add.Enabled = true; //habilita botão add
```

**Limpar Campos**

```
if (nomeTextBox.Enabled == false) { } // se tiver desabilitado ele não limpa nada
else
{
    nomeTextBox.Text = ""; // se não limpa cada campo (fazer uma linha para cada textbox
}
```

**Método Bloq e DesBloq**

```
private void desBloq()
{
    nomeTextBox.Enabled = true; //habilita textBox (fazer uma linha para daca campo
 // o Bloq seria o inverso, ou seja, tudo false
}
```

E fazer esquema de `.Enabled` para cada botão

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas sugestões Leonardo. Mas acho que me expressei mal na pergunta... o que eu precisava na verdade é disparar meu método de desabilitar botões quando o usuário alterar o conteúdo de algum campo da tabela entendeu? Por exemplo, se o usuário começar a alterar o nome do locatário, os botões já devem mudar de configuração, isto é, somente os botões de gravar ou cancelar devem ficar habilitados.
Seria mais ou menos pôr esse método num evento "change" da tabela.

Comment: Dê dois cliques nos TextBox dos campos e coloque no método o comando  `Botão-Gravar.Enabled = true;` e assim por diante, é da mesma forma que está aí, só que ínves de dois cliques no botão tu dá nos campos de preenchimento, ele irá criar um método `TxtBox_TextChanged` daí tu bota os comando pra desativar e ativar os botões dentro dele